# how to extend 2 classes with generic type and different constructor?

Tags: typescript

I am following this exemple =>

[Typescript: How to extend two classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948400/typescript-how-to-extend-two-classes)

In My case, I want to extend a main class =>

```
export class MyClassOne {
   constructor(param1, param2)
}
```

and

```
MyClassTwo<F extends interface1, O extends interface2>{
        constructor(param3, param4)
}
```

So I tried the following

```
const addMyClassOneInheritance = (MyClassOne : { new(...args) }) => {
  return class extends MyClassOne {};
}
const MyFinalClass = addMyClassOneInheritance(MyClassTwo);
export class SynchMapComponent extends MyFinalClass{
```

it works but I don't know a way to set my generic types. because if I had anything within the <> I get an error

> Value of type 'typeof MyClassTwo' is not callable. Did you
>   mean to include 'new'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: How to extend two classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948400/typescript-how-to-extend-two-classes)

Comment: @RannieAguilarPeralta yes thank you... its exactly the link i post in the first line.... I will edit the name then so at least even if people don't click they will know...

Comment: @Bobby could you provide a fuller example of what you are trying to achieve ? The error you posted has nothing to do with the code (`SynchronizatorElement` does not appear in the posted code). To get an answer, a minimal self contained way to reproduce your issue will help

Comment: yes sorry, I changed the naming to make it more clear and forgot to change on the error :=> MyClassTwo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While mixins are a really great concept in general, I feel they don't really address the issue of extending *two* classes in a single one. Rather they enhance *one* class with a fixed set of extra functionality. Actually I don't think it's possible to extend two different, unrelated classes in a single one. But assuming we accept two minor accomodations we can get pretty close:

1. Since the prototype chain is linear, instances of the extended class can only be `instanceof` one of its anchestors (let's say the first).
2. Since TypeScript classes can only implement interfaces with statically known members (and no generic type variables) it's not possible to create a `class` extending two others in a generic way. We'll settle for a factory function instead.

Now, take a look at the following function:

```
type Constructable = new (...args: any[]) => any;

const mergeClasses = <S extends Constructable, T extends Constructable>(class1: S, class2: T) =>
    <Si extends InstanceType<S> = InstanceType<S>, Ti extends InstanceType<T> = InstanceType<T>>
    (args1: ConstructorParameters<S>, args2: ConstructorParameters<T>): Si & Ti => {
        const obj1 = new class1(...args1);
        const obj2 = new class2(...args2);
        for (const p in obj2) {
            obj1[p] = obj2[p];
        }
        return obj1 as Si & Ti;
    };
```

Calling it will return a factory function that constructs object instances implementing both classes originally passed to `mergeClasses`. For example to extend two classes

```
class MyClassOne {
    constructor(param1: number, param2: number) { }
}

class MyClassTwo<F, O> {
    constructor(param3: number, param4: number) { }
}
```

you'd just write the following (omit the type parameters if they're not generic):

```
const instanceFactory = mergeClasses(MyClassOne, MyClassTwo);
const instance = instanceFactory<MyClassOne, MyClassTwo<number, string>>([1, 2], [3, 4]);
```

You can also check out the sample code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructable%20%3D%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mergeClasses%20%3D%20%3CS%20extends%20Constructable%2C%20T%20extends%20Constructable%3E(class1%3A%20S%2C%20class2%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CSi%20extends%20InstanceType%3CS%3E%20%3D%20InstanceType%3CS%3E%2C%20Ti%20extends%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(args1%3A%20ConstructorParameters%3CS%3E%2C%20args2%3A%20ConstructorParameters%3CT%3E)%3A%20Si%20%26%20Ti%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj1%20%3D%20new%20class1(...args1)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj2%20%3D%20new%20class2(...args2)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20p%20in%20obj2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj1%5Bp%5D%20%3D%20obj2%5Bp%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20obj1%20as%20Si%20%26%20Ti%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClassOne%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20param1%3A%20number%2C%20private%20param2%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Hello'%2C%20this.param1%2C%20this.param2)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClassTwo%3CF%2C%20O%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20param3%3A%20number%2C%20private%20param4%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printWorld()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('World'%2C%20this.param3%2C%20this.param4)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instanceFactory%20%3D%20mergeClasses(MyClassOne%2C%20MyClassTwo)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20instanceFactory%3CMyClassOne%2C%20MyClassTwo%3Cnumber%2C%20string%3E%3E(%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%204%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainstance.printHello()%3B%0D%0Ainstance.printWorld()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(instance%20instanceof%20MyClassOne)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(instance%20instanceof%20MyClassTwo)%3B%0D%0A).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example for extending a generic class and same way you can do multiple extends with generic type and even how you can initialize or create instance:

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string;
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper;
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    return new c();
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;   // typechecks!
```

Comment: yes, but what about having double inheritence

so Animal<GenericType1> but also, Mammalian<GenericType2>

and then have a Lion wich extends booth those 2 class?

Comment: I think you need to create a common interface and create an instance for that which extends those two classes so your Lion class will use both the classes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generics to make sure the type of the original class is forwarded to the output of the function. This pattern is outlined [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743).

This code will work as expected keeping all type parameters in the output

```
const addMyClassOneInheritance = <T extends new(...args: any[]) => any>(MyClassOne: T)=> {
    return class extends MyClassOne { };
}

class MyClassTwo<F extends string, O extends number>{
    constructor(param3: F, param4: O) { }
}
const MyFinalClass = addMyClassOneInheritance(MyClassTwo);

export class SynchMapComponent extends MyFinalClass<string, number> {
}


new SynchMapComponent("", 1)
```