# Can we extends multiple classes in NestJS for TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I faced a situation where I want extends multiple classes. I have class A named `a.entity.ts` and I'm extending this class to `BaseEntity` (which is the predefined class in typeORM) as follow:

```
@Entity()
export class A extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column({length: 100, nullable: true})
    description: string;
}
```

Also, I have my own custom `abstract class DateAudit` for Auditing date purpose as follow:

```
export abstract class DateAudit {
    
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created: Date;
  
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated: Date;
  }
```

I want to use this `DateAudit` along with `BaseEntity` class in my **class A** like :

> export class A extends BaseEntity, DateAudit

I know multiple inheritances are not possible. Looking forward to knowing how I can achieve this type of scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For some who looking for a solution, this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948400/typescript-how-to-extend-two-classes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```js
export abstract class DateAudit extends BaseEntity {
    
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created: Date;
  
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated: Date;
  }
```

then your entity will do:

```js
@Entity()
export class A extends DateAudit {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column({length: 100, nullable: true})
    description: string;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**SOLUTION 1**  
To inherit columns in TypeORM you need to write an abstract class that your entity will inherit from, in your case you can do something:

```
    export type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function BaseEntity<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    abstract class AbstractBase extends Base {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
          id: number;

        @Column()
         title: string;

       @Column({length: 100, nullable: true})
        description: string;
    }
    return AbstractBase;
}

export function DateAudit<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    abstract class AbstractBase extends Base {
        @CreateDateColumn()
            created: Date;

        @UpdateDateColumn()
           updated: Date;
    }
    return AbstractBase;
}

export class EmptyClass {}
```

To implement it :

```
    @Entity()
export class A extends DateAudit(BaseEntity(EmptyClass)){
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column({length: 100, nullable: true})
    description: string;
}
```

*ps: inspired by solution from github*

**Solution 2 : is to use *Embedded Entities***

In your case, we going to extend the `baseEntity`, on the other hand
we going to create a class for `auditEntity`

```
    export class DateAudit {
    
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created: Date;
  
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated: Date;
  }
```

Then we can connect those columns in your entity :

```
       @Entity()
export class A extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column({length: 100, nullable: true})
    description: string;

   @Column(type => DateAudit )
    audit: DateAudit ;
}
```

*ps: the colmun will take `audit` as a prefix*  
source : [embedded-entities](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/embedded-entities.md)

Comment: Thanks @youba for this solution, this works fine. The only issue is that if you, for some reason, what to have any kind of relation in the abstract class, like ManyToOne, you cannot reference back to EntityWithTenant as it is not a BaseEntity.

Imagine you have TenantType entity
class TenantType extends BaseEntity {
...

@OneToMany(() => EntityWithTenant, entitiyWithTenant => entitiyWithTenant.tenantType)
entityWithTenant: EntityWithTenant
}

are there any work around inside for that too?