# Merging two classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have two classes.

`UserDto`

```
export class UserDto {
  name: string;
}
```

`AuthDto`

```
export class AuthDto {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

I want to create a class of `RegistrationDto`, which will be a merge of these two classes.

I tried to do this

```
export class RegisterDto extends UserDto, AuthDto {}
```

But this only works for interfaces. I am using it as `Nestjs` dtos, so if I'm thinking about it in the wrong way, please let me know.

How do I handle the classes in this case?

Comment: Where are these classes coming from? Why don't you turn them into interfaces?

Comment: Similar to a question I called this morning. I got the solution from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26961710/8015757. Also, I asked a similar question a while ago. I think everyone is having the same problem today. lol

Comment: Huh. Interesting. @ChrisG Huh. Good point. Didn't know Nest accepts interfaces. Thanks! You can add it as answer so I can select as best if you'd like. Unless there is some drawbacks for this approach

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `AuthDto` to `UserDto` or vice-versa:

```js
export class AuthDto extends UserDto {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

And then do this:

```js
export class RegisterDto extends AuthDto {}
```

Just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you consolidate them to a new class:

```
export class RegisterDto{
    authDto: AuthDto;
    userDto: UserDto;
}
```

Comment: This kind of works. But I'd have to  mess with the body content for Nest though. Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both the DTO's into one using the Intersection Type

```
import { IntersectionType } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class RegisterDto extends IntersectionType(
  AuthDto,
  UserDto,
) {}
```

Reference: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types#intersection