# How to make class follow some interface contract with implementation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I know that interface are just contracts and they do not provide implementations.For example when i have

```
interface ISomething {
  exportJson():boolean;
}


export class AppComponent implements ISomething {

}
```

to implement the interface i will do the following

```
export class AppComponent implements ISomething {
  exportJson(): boolean {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

when i implement this interface i want specific logic inside - automatically for example

```
exportJson(): boolean {
    let getJsonPath = '';
    // some oher IMPLEMENTATION LOGIC
    return true;
  }
```

if i try with classes

```
class Something {
  exportJson() {
    let getJsonPath = '';
    // some oher IMPLEMENTATION LOGIC
    return true;
  }
}


export class AppComponent extends Something {
}
```

then i will have the implementation of the exportJson but there is not contract between, by cotnract i mean that the exportJson method must be implemented - we get error when we are not implementing some method from the interface.

Is there way for this ?

Comment: Why not something like a [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)? Why much around with interfaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: How to extend two classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948400/typescript-how-to-extend-two-classes)

Comment: To the person that closed this question: Where you saw in this question that i need to extend from two classes ?! I asked other thing

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, why did you remove `implements ISomething` from `class Something`?